# Redirecting to a route after creating an entity in JHipster

Tags: angular, jhipster

I am trying to redirect to a different route after an entity is successfully created. The two entities I am dealing with are ProjectNote and Project. I have tried to use router.navigate in the onSaveSuccess function but this does not work.

Any help greatly appreciated?

```
private onSaveSuccess(result: ProjectNote) {   
    this.eventManager.broadcast({ name: 'projectNoteListModification', content: 'OK'});
    this.isSaving = false;
    this.activeModal.dismiss(result);
    console.log('Navigating to : /project/' + result.project.id );

    this.zone.run(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['/project/' + result.project.id]);
      });
}
```

Comment: did you try it without the this.zone.run... ?

Comment: yep I have tried it with and without this.zone.run - no luck